# An error occurred running the iOS Simulator (ios-sim exit code 1)

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator

Following are the system version details :

**a) Appcelerator Studio - 4.3.3**

**b) OS X - 10.10.5**

**c) XCode - 7.2**

**d) Node JS - 2.11.3**

When I try to run in iOS similator than erro comes like :

```
[INFO] : Launching iOS Simulator 
[ERROR] : Project failed to build after 1m 16s 628ms 
[ERROR] : An error occurred running the iOS Simulator (ios-sim exit code 1) 
TRACE | titanium exited with exit code 1 
ERROR | Error: ti run exited with error code 1 
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/flexsin/.appcelerator/install/5.0.4/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66) 
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) 
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12) 
TRACE | Sending exit signal to titanium process: 31468
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to multiple installations of Xcode and incorrect iOS SDK Home value set in Titanium Studio Preferences, which maybe pointing to a different location of Xcode than the current one or the needed one.

I was on Xcode 5.1 and iOS SDK 7.1 with iOS simulator version 7.1. The Titanium SDK version in my tiapp.xml is 3.3.0.GA. I had multiple installations of Xcode ranging from Xcode 4.5, 5.0, 5.0.2 and 5.1 on my Mac machine running Mac Mavericks. I was able to solve it the following way -

From the Titanium Studio menu options, select Preferences.
From the Preferences window, expand the Studio drop down and inside that expand the Platforms drop down and select iOS.
Under the General section on the right, check if the iOS SDK Home is set to the current version as per the Run Configuration you are building the app against. For me, it was set to Xcode 5.0.2 version when it should have been actually set to Xcode 5.1 version (I guess needed for running on iOS simulator version 7.1 with Titanium SDK version 3.3.0.GA). You can find the steps to change it by clicking on the More Details link provided in the Note below.
Click Apply and run the application again, better even to do a clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Its run in iOS Simulator when I changed
 `Xcode version 6.4`

Answer (score 0):

This is a compatibility issue.  Please check the xcode and Titanium SDK matrix.
For SDK 4 you will need xcode 6.4 max, not 7.2.  You can run multiple versions of xcode on a mac, just run a command line to select the appropriate version.

This issue is typical when you migrate from another Mac and automatically install the newest version of xcode.

older versions of xcode:
developer.apple.com/download/more/

compatibility matrix:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix

command line:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/install-multiple-versions-of-xcode.html